Compare 2 time ranges to see if there is a convergence
I am putting together a small booking system, where it displays time slots (every 30 minutes).
I want to be able to highlight when there is a booking that falls within that time slot.
So, I have a DateTime FROM and a DateTime TO for the Time Slot
I then have bookings DateTime FROM and a DateTime TO for the Time Slot
I can't work out how to flag to the timeslot that there is a booking that (at least partially) occupies that time slot.
I am trying this comparizon to identify if a record exists, but it is not flagging correctly.
There is probably a better method for doing this. Any pointers?
var checkbookings = bookings
   .Where(i => i.StartTime.TimeOfDay >= timeslot.StartTime.TimeOfDay)
   .Where(i => i.EndTime.TimeOfDay <= timeslot.EndTime.TimeOfDay)
   .FirstOrDefault();

The bookings object has already been enumerated from the database using ToList().

I'd suggest using a timespan instead of just comparing raw points in time as you are, then you can test whether the span contains your booking.

First, you don't need 2 Where clauses, you can use one with &&. More importantly though, calling TimeOnlygenerates a convesion operation that prevents the use of any indexes onStartTimeandEndTime. If you care about time use the timetype in the database andTimeOnly` in C#.

Can timeslot.StartTime and timeslot.EndTime be on different days?

I know I don;t need 2 where clauses, buit it makes it a little more readable at the moment whilst I am still working on it.

@MaximilianBurszley the client-side type doesn't affect the query. The database type does though. This LINQ query generates cast(starttime as time)>=@t1 which prevents the use of indexes

@TimSchmelter no, would be on same day

LINQ is a feature of iterators, not databases @PanagiotisKanavos

@PanagiotisKanavos Ok, so if I kept the time only in a dedicated column in the database for the booking, and used TimeOnly in c# for the timeslot, how do I check for a match?

@MaximilianBurszley and EF Core, just like this question

@MaximilianBurszley thanks, how would i compare 2 timespans to give me the same result?

You would construct a timespan over the time slot and test whether the booking start/end are contained inside it.

@PanagiotisKanavos You're inferring something that isn't there.  This question is only tagged with c# and is only asking about comparing datetimes.

@MaximilianBurszley but a TimeSpan is just a time right? So If the timeslot was from 15:30 - 16:00, how would I express that as a TimeSpan?

@MaximilianBurszley no, just written quite a few temporal queries over the years, to the point that I remember the simplified condition instinctively. You're talking about timespan as if it was a period (in temporal DB terms). In C# TimeSpan is a duration and can't help here at all

The logical condition, after a bit of boolean simplification, and assuming the fields are time and TimeOnly is  :
.Where(i => timeslot.StartTime <= i.EndTime &&
            timeslot.EndTime   >= i.StartTime)

What you ask is equivalent to asking whether two linear segments overlap. If you draw the two time segments on a line they'll look like this :
T-Start      T-End
|-------------|

    I-Start             I-End
       |------------------|

No matter which segment is first or last, one's start is before the other's end.
Update
This condition handles the set overlap. If T-End and I-Start are the same logically, they still overlap. In a booking system though, we wouldn't consider this an overlap. While one option is to ensure end times are "just before" the actual end, a cleaner solution would be to use <
.Where(i => timeslot.StartTime < i.EndTime &&
            timeslot.EndTime   > i.StartTime)

T-Start      T-End
|-------------|

           I-Start             I-End
              |------------------|


Often we have including StartTime but excluding EndTime, in this case >= and <= should be changed into > and <

The question is about overlap. If I-Start and T-End are the same, the segments logically still overlap. But yes, that may not be what the OP intends

@DmitryBychenko it's a bit weird that I remembered the simplified condition before I remembered why it works.

@PanagiotisKanavos This was excellent. Thank you. I had to do a bit of refactoring and as its .NET 7 (not moved it to 8 yet) had to add a datatype converter but its now having the desired effect. Thank you!

@MatthewWarr in .NET 7 and lower you can use TimeSpan instead of TimeOnly.
